# CEO Compensation in Banking Data

Tags: data-request, wages

My main goal is to compare CEO compensation for banks across different countries.

Does anybody know where I can find data on CEO compensation for banks for different countries or a paper which contains at least a qualitative ranking? In the end I want to have a ranking for a certain number of countries of the form: Payment country 1 > Payment country 2 > Payment country 3 .... . I know from the literature that in the US CEO compensation should be the highest, followed by the UK. But most sources I found are not free to use (like Execucomp) and this paper (https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1592163) gives a rather strange ordering where the CEO compensation in the UK is very low.

A paper with a table and

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to obtain this info from listed companies in the US and UK, but also in other countries.

Most publicly listed firms are obliged to report CEO compensation. [Here's an example for Qualcomm](http://insiders.morningstar.com/trading/executive-compensation.action?t=QCOM&region=usa&culture=en-US).